# How to only execute an Observable if term is not null/empty?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have the following code inside my constructor:

```
this.searchResults = this.searchTerm.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(500)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(term => this.apiService.search({
        limit: this.searchResultsLimit,
        term: term
    }));
```

And this is my input

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="searchTerm" />
```

You can see the tutorial I followed to get the code [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html#putting-some-sugar-on-top).

My API service method is as followed:

```
searchCompanies(options): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.jsonp.get('api/search', this.formatOptions(options)).map(res => {   
        return res.json();
    });
}
```

Each time `searchTerm` is changed inside my input, the API call is fired. My problem is that the call is fired even when my input is empty (such as typing a query, then backspacing it all).

My question is, how can I only get my observable to fire when the value of `searchTerm is not empty/null?

Comment: You can have a if condition in the constructor

Comment: Wouldn't it be simply to do a check on your service?

Comment: @developer033 - My service is a straight observable. I'll make an edit to the question with the method now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to avoid the API call and want the search results to be reset when the search term is empty, test for an empty string in `switchMap` and return an empty observable in that situation:

```js
this.searchResults = this.searchTerm
  .valueChanges
  .debounceTime(500)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => term ?
    this.apiService.search({
      limit: this.searchResultsLimit,
      term: term
    }) :
    // If search term is empty, return an empty array
    // or whatever the API's response for no matches
    // would be:
    Observable.of([]) 
  });
```

Comment: Neat. But unfortunately, the `searchResults` does not get emptied when the `term` is empty/null.

Comment: Well, in that case you should return whatever the API would return if there was no match. For example, to return an empty array, replace `Observable.empty()` with `Observable.of([])`.

Answer (score 39):

Most easily just use the `filter()` operator to filter out all empty `term`s:

```
this.searchResults = this.searchTerm.valueChanges
    .filter(term => term) // or even better with `filter(Boolean)`
    .debounceTime(500)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(term => this.apiService.search({
        limit: this.searchResultsLimit,
        term: term
    }));
```

Comment: Works seamlessly. Although it then leaves the issue of `this.searchResults` being the value of the last returned results from the API service when `term` is empty. How could `this.searchResults` be set to `null` or `undefined` if the search term is empty?

Comment: Your `this.searchResults` hold the Observable so you probably don't want to override it.

Comment: `filter` saved my date.

Comment: use filter as`.filter(term => term != null)`

Comment: Really this should be the answer

Answer (score 2):

In Rxjs 6 so updated to use `pipe` you can stop the observable from processing so nothing is propagated downstream using `EMPTY`:

```js
this.searchResults = this.searchTerm.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500)
      distinctUntilChanged()
      switchMap(term => 
        (term) 
          // If the term exists make a request
          ? this.apiService.search({ limit: this.searchResultsLimit, term: term })
          // Otherwise, stop all processing
          : EMPTY
      )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to self... if you're going crazy thinking that `null` is still passing by the filter, then make sure it's not actually a string like `'null'`.

Comment: You might check for 'undefined', '0' 'false' then....